Issue with React Native AsyncStorage and updating state with new data
I'm facing an issue with managing data retrieval from AsyncStorage in my React Native application. I'm using AsyncStorage to store orders, and I want to dynamically update my component whatever a new order is added to AsyncStorage. However, I do not know how to this
`
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import CartItems from "../../../components/cartItems";

function CartPage() {
  let order = [];

  async function getCartData() {
    try {
      const orderDataFromStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem("order");
      if (orderDataFromStorage) {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(orderDataFromStorage);
        order.push(parsedData)
        AsyncStorage.removeItem("order");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {getCartData}, [])

  return (
    <View>
      <CartItems orders={order} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default CartPage;



Issue: The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to dynamically update my CartPage component whatever a new order is added to AsyncStorage. Currently, my component does not reflect the new data.
Desired Outcome: I want the CartPage component to update and display all orders, including any newly added ones, dynamically whenever a new order is added to AsyncStorage.
What I've Tried: I've used the getCartData function inside a useEffect hook to retrieve data from AsyncStorage, but it doesn't seem to update the component correctly.
Additional Information: The structure of data saved in AsyncStorage is JSON formatted as { "chosedAddon": [], "order": ["Tom & Jerry", "Fries, mozzarella, tomato"], "price": 8, "quantity": 1 }.é.

From your example the useEffect will only run once, on initial load.  The second parameter [] needs to have:

useEffect(() => {... logic}) - runs on every render
useEffect(() => {... logic}, []) - runs once on component load
useEffect(() => {... logic}, [ dependencies e.g. order]) - runs every time this value changes.

I would also use useState on the order to keep track of changes.
So the changes could be
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import CartItems from "../../../components/cartItems";

function CartPage() {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState([]);

  async function getCartData() {
    try {
      const orderDataFromStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem("order");
      if (orderDataFromStorage) {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(orderDataFromStorage);
        order.push(parsedData)
        AsyncStorage.removeItem("order");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {await getCartData()}, [order])

  return (
    <View>
      <CartItems orders={order} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default CartPage;


I just noticed there is also an issue with the function if you use the order as a dependency.  You're going to get a cyclic loop.  You're attempting to update the object you're depending on.  You need to separate out your logic for retrieving, removing, and saving.   With useState you'll need to change it to setOrder([...order, parsedData]).

Also, as an architectural note, AsyncStorage is there to persist state, so you can come back to it.  Once loaded, useState/useEffect are your tools.  You want to check/load from storage upon first component load, after that you want to use state and write to storage upon state changes to keep them in sync.

In useEffect you need to add () to the function i.e getCartData().
Further you can also add a dependency in useEffect like this.
import { useIsFocused } from "react-native";

const isFocus = useIsFocused();

useEffect(()=>{
   getCartData()
},[isFocus])

It will fetch data when ever this screen is in focus.
